# Why is there no tag for WAMP?

Tags: discussion

I was surprised to find no defined tag for the WAMP stack.  Is it considered off-topic?  There exists a tag for XAMPP, though.

Comment: It is just not a common problem, so the search is good enough to find the questions about that.

Comment: Seems like a blurry line between Super User and WPSE

Comment: @Howdy_McGee Didn't realize superuser.com had WAMP content, good to know, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: There's plenty of tags for things that are offtopic, you shouldn't take a tag as implying something is on or off topic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WordPress can live in many different forms on many different platforms. WAMP is a popular Windows server setup for "Apache, MySQL, and php", the three services needed for WordPress to run.

Given there are many different configurations of these services on many different platforms, WPSE might get overcome with questions that involve services rather than software.

Comment: True, but would also be a reason to skip the XAMPP tag.